# Assign ethernet alias to KVM guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, libvirt-guests

I have a pool of IP addresses and a single ethernet cable. I have set aliases:

```
auto enp2s0:0
iface enp2s0:0 inet static
  address x.x.x.x
  netmask x.x.x.x
```

I want to dedicate some of the aliases to a libvirt kvm guest, so that the ip is set from inside the guest.

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1/ remove your aliases

2/ setup a bridge (package name : bridge-utils), and add enp2s0 nic inside

3/ setup your kvm guests to use bridged networking, and use the bridge previously created

4/ inside the guest, configure ipv4 to use one of your ip